# Why does image augmentation decrease my test accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm implementing a classifier for CIFAR10. I cannot really disclose the details of my model architecture, but it's based on the Resnet56.
When I was training without image augmentation, my model reached a test accuracy of 92.65% and a training accuracy of 99.66%.
On the other hand, when training with image augmentation, the test accuracy was only 90.79% and the training accuracy was 99.44%.
How is this even possible? The little decrease in training accuracy is perfectly understandable, but shouldn't the test accuracy increase because of the augmentation?
The augmentation I used is the same as in the Resnet paper, namely random horizontal flip and a padding of 4 pixels followed by a random crop of 32x32 pixels (this is the same as a random translation).

Comment: No way to tell without knowing what you actually did in both cases

Comment: I mean just theoretically, if I have an arbitrary model, how could image augmentation decrease accuracy? Also I updated the question with the augmentation method I used

Comment: Short answer, if you're over fitting. This could happen if your model found (probably spurious) relationships in your data that the augmentation removed. Example, class 1 often coincides with some pixel pattern on the left, class 2 has the pattern on the right.  Your model discovered this. Augmentation removed that relationship, so accuracy decreased.

Comment: @bogovicj OP refers to test accuracy not the training accuracy.